# javascript onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to call updatemission function when text in first input box is changed and updatemissionpoints when text in second input box is changed, but it is not working here.
Here is the html code snippet from where i am calling these two functions

```
<input id="mission-{{mission.id}}" onchange="updatemission(mission.id, mission.missioninfo)" type="text" ng-model="mission.missionInfo" class="form-control" >

<input id="point-{{missioncontent.id}}" type="text" ng-model="missioncontent.info" class="form-control">
```

these are the javascript functions

```
$scope.updatemission = function(missionid, info){
        alert("changed");
    };

    $scope.updatemissionpoints = function(missionpointid, info){

    };
```

I want these functions to be called when all the editing is done in the text boxes. I am using angular js, so solution with angular js or jquery will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-blur - angular

```
<input id="mission-{{mission.id}}" ng-blur="updatemission(mission.id, mission.missioninfo)" type="text" ng-model="mission.missionInfo" class="form-control" >

<input id="point-{{missioncontent.id}}" type="text" ng-model="missioncontent.info" class="form-control" ng-blur="updatemissionpoints(missioncontent.id, missioncontent.info) ">
```

Comment: read about it on : https://docs.angularjs.org/api?PHPSESSID=cae8e98e7ca559b4605d75c813b358ee

Comment: but ng-change calls the function even if a single letter is changed i want to call it when all the editing id done,

Comment: You can use ng-blur when the user input finishes and the mouse leaves the textbox.

Comment: thats why i chose to use onchange, it calls the function when focus is removed from the text box

Comment: Welcome. Accept the answer as it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think Best thing you can do is the using [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive here.

`ng-change` will > Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input.

`onchange` is out of angular scope *(onchange is javascript change event and its not **directly** related to the angular)* so it doesn't call the scope property you pass to the `onchange` event. But `ng-change` will execute the scope property you have passed.

```
<input id="mission-{{mission.id}}" ng-change="updatemission(mission.id, mission.missioninfo)" type="text" ng-model="mission.missionInfo" class="form-control" >
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTFvKMfdjr0z8WDxKFd5?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Try using JavaScript's onblur

```
<input id="point-{{missioncontent.id}}" type="text" ng-model="missioncontent.info" class="form-control">
```

That way when the object loses focus the script runs